# dlclose gets implicitly called

Tags: c, shared-libraries

So I was studying about shared libraries and I read that an implicit `dlclose()` is performed upon process termination.
I want to know who is responsible for this call. For example, if I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
}
```

And then if I did `ldd ./a.out` then I get a list of these libraries:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd6675c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2569866000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000562b69162000)
```

Linker is responsible for loading these right, so who is responsible upon termination of this `./a.out` executable for implicit `dlclose()` of these libraries?

Comment: This must be a mistake. No `dlclose` is called upon process termination.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I am studying from Michael Kerrisk's The Linux Programming Interface, a well established book for system programming and it is clearly mentioned there in the book that `An implicit dlclose() of all libraries is performed on process termination.`

Comment: When a process terminates, all its open file handles are automatically closed. Since a DL is just an open file, this implies that they get closed as well.

Comment: It is hard to tell what he had in mind, but at `exit()` (not process termination) shared object destructors are called, which also happens when you call `dlclose()`. No destructors are called when a process exits by other means (e.g. `_exit()`), so whatever happens at the moment of proper termination is not equivalent to `dlclose()`.

Comment: @barmar `dlclose` does more than closing a file handle.

Comment: @n.m., are you suggesting that, for example, if a process's only thread terminates by calling `_exit()` then the reference counts for its shared libraries are not decremented?

Comment: @n.m. What else does it do that matters to a terminated process?

Comment: @Barmar calls destructors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No I'm not suggesting that. The reference counts for its shared libraries are just reference counts for open files. They go down like all other reference counts for open files.

Comment: So from all the answers here, is it correct to conclude that what the statement `an implicit dlclose()` meant is that upon process termination, the library handles are released that is the open count reference to the library is decremented instead of a full fledged call to `dlclose()`?

Answer (score 6):

I do not have Kerrisk's book, but if you have accurately characterized its contents then they seem to be a bit simplified.  It is not strictly correct to say that whenever a process terminates, the function `dlclose()` is called for each of its open shared libraries, but it is reasonable to say that whenever a process terminates, all its handles on open shared libraries are closed.  As a result, the operating system recognizes that one fewer process references each of those shared libraries, and if that brings any shared libraries' reference counts to zero then the OS may choose to unload them from memory.

`dlclose()` does more work than that.  In particular, it causes any destructor functions in the library to run.  Those functions will also run when the process exits normally by returning from `main()` or by calling `exit()`, but not if the process terminates by other means, such as calling `_exit()` or in response to receiving a signal.  In the normal-exit case, the net effect may be the same as if `dlclose()` were called for each open shared library, but even then, that's not necessarily achieved by actually calling `dlclose()`.

Finally, do be aware that although the `dl*()` functions are defined by POSIX, substantially all details of dynamic / shared libraries are left at the discretion of implementations.  Since you've asked about a Linux book, I've referenced a few Linux-specific details.

Comment: So is it correct if I conclude that instead of a full fledged call to `dlclose()` what Kerrisk meant is that the open count reference to that library is decremented?

Comment: @AbhinavJain, my answer already contains all I have to say about Kerrisk's intentions: I'm inclined to guess that he was simplifying rather than providing altogether false information.  Having not read the book myself, however, all I can do is describe the relevant behavior, as I have done, and let you reconcile that with the book for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the book is only talking about normal process termination when calling `exit()` or returning from `main()`. `dlopen()` presumably registers an `atexit()` handler that executes all the termination functions of the dynamic libraries.

It's not feasible for libraries to execute any code when a process is terminated abnormally. If the process is terminated by the OS instead of by exiting normally, the OS just releases any file handles, but it won't execute code in the context of the process.

Comment: Yes, my wording was a little imprecise. I meant (and should have written) "normal termination (via exit())." (Returning from main() is course equivalent to exit().)